# Sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithms, sorting

[image]

I want to know from this picture which one is bubble sort, insertion sort and selection sort?

My answer is:

1. bubble sort algorithm,
2. insertion sort algorithm,
3. selection sort algorithm.

Is it this right?
Is there reference link too to picture which one is the right sort?

Comment: This site is not (supposed to be) a homework answering service.Can you ask a more specific question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you get it right.

First row: in the second picture, we can see that the lower part are sorted and almost every element has been moved, which we can assume that is a bubble algorithm that moves the lower values to bottom.

Second row: we can observe that along the four pictures the algorithm is starting to sort the left part of the data. This indicate that the algorithm is exploring the data from left to right and insert each explored element in right position on the explored data (insertion sort).

Third row: from the second picture, the algorithm is searching for the lowest value and sort it ( selection sort)

Comment: ＠Nicekiller231  thankyou but what makes you said it is right?

Comment: First row: in the second picture, we can see that the upper and the lower part are sort it, which we can assume that is a double bubble algorithm that moves the low values to bottom and  the high values to the top.
Second row: we can observe that along the four pictures the algorithm is starting to sort the lower part of the data. This indicate that the algorthem is exploring the data and insert each explored element in right position on the explored data (insertion sort).
Third row: from the second picture, the algorithm is serching for the lowest value and sort it ( selection sort)